# Scripting screen for multiple deattached windows

Tags: bash, scripting, gnu-screen

I've combed through as many of the gnu-screen and bash tags as I can find and I can't quite find the answer, so forgive me if I've missed an obvious one.

As part of a bash script, I need to create a deattached screen session and have it run a command in the newly created window 1 of that session, then another command in the newly created window 2, all part of the same session. What I have so far successfully creates the session deattached, names it, and gets my python script running in window 1. The problem is that it will never open a second window. What am I missing?

```
screen -d -m -S jsession
screen -S jsession -p 0 -X exec /script/pyscript.py
screen -S jsession -p 1 -X exec asterisk -rvvvvvvvvvv
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the second window before you can send a command to it. The first window is created when the session is started, which is why the first `exec` works. For the other window, just replace `exec` with `screen`, to start the new window.

```
screen -d -m -S jsession
screen -S jsession -p 0 -X exec /script/pyscript.py

# No need to specify a window with -p; the new one will be numbered
# automatically
screen -S jsession -X screen asterisk -rvvvvvvvvvv
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That fixed that issue. This may be a problem completely that I'll have to figure out, but I thought I'd throw this out there. If I run this in a script, it acts as if it's not running as root, and the python script doesn't do everything it should.  But, when I create the screen session and run these commands manually, it works fine. Does screen run differently privilege wise when scripted?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that (having switched to `tmux` a while back), but I think the command should run as the same user that invokes `screen`.

Comment: I just wrote another bash script in Tmux to do the same thing. Tmux is definitely easier. I'm still having the same problem. It must be something related to the privileges when scripting things in asterisk. I'll head down that path I guess, unless anyone else has any ideas...